# Scrollbar visibility detection in event handler

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have a side panel with a toggle button for narrow/wide view.
On toggle, if scrollbar becomes visible (overflow), it should hide the toggle button.

Instead of calling `hideOrShowToggleBtn` directly, i added a private property that i can use in `ngAfterViewChecked` to call it once per event and (hopefully) after view has been updated.

However if i toggle to narrow view and scrollbar becomes visible - `element.clientHeight element.scrollHeight` are identical and scrollbar is not detected.
Possibly because `ngAfterViewChecked` fires too early.

Would there be a better way to detect it and ensure dom is up to date and i am not checking a old view before scrollbar is actually added?

```
@ViewChild('content') private mainContentDiv: ElementRef;

onSidebarToggleClick() {
    this.largeSidebar = !this.largeSidebar;
    this.sidebarToggled = true;
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.sidebarToggled) {
        this.hideOrShowToggleBtn();
    }
}

hideOrShowToggleBtn() {
    let element = this.mainContentDiv.nativeElement;

    let style = element.ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, undefined);
    let hasScrollbar = (style.overflowY === 'auto' && element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight);
    this.hideToggle = !hasScrollbar && !this.largeSidebar;
    this.sidebarToggled = false;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

html:

```
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <i class="sidebar-header-toggle fa fa-2x cursor"
               (click)="onSidebarToggleClick()"
            ></i>
        </div>
        <div #content [ngClass]="{'sidebar-large': largeSidebar, 'sidebar-small': !largeSidebar }">

        </div>
```

Simplified Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tv2quvCmzElZzidiRjTZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while of trying - it all came down to CSS3 animations -  angular was not aware of it. I had a 0.4s transition so the dom was actually updated 0.4s after the event.

To fix this, i switched to angular animations, for a simple guide:
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/25/Understanding-Angular-2-Animations-Tutorial

In short:

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

animations: [
    trigger('slidePanel', [
        state('small', style({
            width: '300px'
        })),
        state('large', style({
            width: '570px'
        })),
        transition('small => large', animate('400ms ease-in')),
        transition('large => small', animate('400ms ease-out'))
    ]),
]
```

And adding this to my div i wanted to animate:

```
[@slidePanel]='state'
```

Then updating the `state` property value in my click handler.